# Copying and renaming multiple files in a .bat file with FOR ... DO xcopy

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I want to move several thousand files (.jpg and .pdf) from one location to another and then rename each file.

My 'copy_rename_docs.csv' input file contains two columns:

- the first column containing the original path AND file names for each file that I want to move and rename
- and the second column containing the new paths AND file names that I want to move and rename each file to

like this:

```
\\myapp\data\e3\9b\e39bf5e8d745833418d3edcd97c6c7589716970b,\\myapp\test_migration\e3\9b\Test File-xxx - SS1.pdf
\\myapp\data\09\f5\09f58d1a1345f67a36154e99ffedb27308fa4292,\\myapp\test_migration\09\f5\nxf7.pdf
```

so "e39bf5e8d745833418d3edcd97c6c7589716970b" is a SHA1 hash of "Test File-xxx - SS1.pdf"

To copy and rename the files I tried this batch file:

```php
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a IN (copy_rename_docs.csv) DO (xcopy /e /i "%%a" "%%b\*")
pause
exit
```

But instead of copying and renaming the files to this:

```
\\myapp\test_migration\e3\9b\Test File-xxx - SS1.pdf
\\myapp\test_migration\09\f5\nxf7.pdf
```

It is creating a FOLDER for each file with the FILE names as the FOLDER names and copying the files with their original file names into each FOLDER, like this:

```
\\myapp\test_migration\e3\9b\Test File-xxx - SS1.pdf\e39bf5e8d745833418d3edcd97c6c7589716970b
\\myapp\test_migration\09\f5\nxf7.pdf\09f58d1a1345f67a36154e99ffedb27308fa4292
```

What I want is:

```
\\myapp\test_migration\e3\9b\Test File-xxx - SS1.pdf
\\myapp\test_migration\09\f5\nxf7.pdf
```

What's wrong with my batch file?

And is xcopy the best tool for this?

Comment: To begin with, your question states, **move**, not copy, so why would you be using a copying command? Either use `move` or use `robocopy` with its `/mov` option, _(robocopy superseded xcopy a good thriteen years ago)_. BTW, this would be a little safer, `for /f "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=," %%a in ("copy_rename_docs.csv") do …`

Comment: Please also take a look at the output from `xcopy /?`, and ask yourself, if this looks correct, `xcopy /e /i "\\myapp\data\e3\9b\e39bf5e8d745833418d3edcd97c6c7589716970b" "\\myapp\test_migration\e3\9b\Test File-xxx - SS1.pdf\*"`. Also you can find out how to use robocopy, by opening a Command Prompt window, typing `robocopy /?`, and pressing the `[ENTER]` key.

Comment: I fixed the question heading - it's a Copy question, not a Move question. Apologies. 

I need to copy the files, not move them.

Comment: Either way, use the `robocopy` command, without its `/mov` option.